# how to know if all matched elements have been hidden using slideUp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this test here: http://jsbin.com/epihis/2/edit

where I have three paragraphs that slideUp one after other when clicked. Once all the paragrapths have been hidden, i want to show a button to slideDown them.

How do I do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){ 

     //jQuery mouseover function
       $("p#hovercolor").mouseover(function(){
        $("p#hovercolor").css("background-color","yellow");
       });

     //jQuery mouseout function
      $("p#hovercolor").mouseout(function(){
        $("p#hovercolor").css("background-color","green");
      });

     //jQuery click function
    $('input[name="Colorbtn"]').click(function(){
        $('.myBox').css('background', '#00aeef');
        $('.myBox').css('color', '#fff');
     });

     $('input[name="discolorbtn"]').click(function(){
        $('.myBox').css('background', '#fff');
        $('.myBox').css('color', '#000');
     });

     //Hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.
     $('p.sliderhider').click(function(){
       $(this).slideUp(); 
     });


  });    

</script>
</head>
<body>

  <p id="hovercolor">Move the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>

  <div class="myBox" style="border:1px solid blue; width:150px; height:150px; margin-bottom:20px;">
    BOX 1
  </div>

  <input type="button" value="Color myBox" name="Colorbtn"/>
  <input type="button" value="Dis-Color myBox" name="discolorbtn"/><br /><br />
  <hr>
  <p class="sliderhider" style="display:block; background: yellow; width:200px">Slide this up one at a time</p>
  <p class="sliderhider" style="display:block; background: yellow; width:200px">Slide this up one at a time</p>
  <p class="sliderhider" style="display:block; background: yellow; width:200px">Slide this up one at a time</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not try `.toggle()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `slideUp` callback write a condition to check if all `p.sliderhider` are hidden.

```
//Hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.
 $('p.sliderhider').click(function(){
   $(this).slideUp({'complete': function () {
     if ($('p.sliderhider:visible').length == 0) {
       $('#showPara').show();
     }        
   }}); 
 });

 $('#showPara').click(function (){
    $('p.sliderhider').slideDown();
 });
```

If yes, show the button which could `slideDown` all `.sliderhider`

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/epihis/5

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 $('p.sliderhider').click(function () {
     $(this).slideUp(function () {
         if ($('p.sliderhider:visible').length === 0) {
             $('hr').after('<button id="show">Button</button>')
         };
     });
 });
 $(document).on('click', '#show', function () {
     $('p.sliderhider').show();
 })
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zWu6m/)**

In the slideUp's callback you can check the length of the visible paragraphs and when there are none left, generate the button to show them again.

Comment: Good use of `:visible`. Good idea.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery lets you pass a callback, that will be fired once the animation is complete:

```
$('p.sliderhider').click(function(){
    $(this).slideUp({'complete': function() {
        // show "slide down" button here
    }}); 
});
```

Comment: that call back is for each matched element slideUp. I want to make sure all elements have gone through slideUp, so the all disappear. Now after making sure all have disappeared, show a button to show them all.

Comment: You could increment a counter, and when that counter reached the number of paragraphs, execute the slidedown.